# Send an email using Outlook

Tags: javascript, html

I need whenever the user clicks on a button , open outlook and send email from it with filling the subject field.

I have already done it using :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rajnishkaushik/archive/2007/05/06/compose-and-send-e-mail-from-javascript-by-using-outlook-automation-2007.aspx

The only issue I have that I don't want to set manually from IE the "Initialize and script ActiveX control not marked as safe for scripting".

Are there any solutions !!

Comment: Have you tried a simple `mailto:` URL? It should do what you need without the need for any additional scripting

Comment: What if the user hasn't got Outlook?  Will any email client do, or are you specifically wanting Outlook?

Comment: @Pekka: Ys I've tried it but it opens your default email.

Comment: There is no sane way to explicitly start Outlook on a client machine. What you have is the best you can get - and it will work on IE only.

Comment: @Dreams:In that case I will use any other mail client.But in case s/he has the outlook,it should be used.

Answer (score 3):

If Outlook isn't requirement and you don't care about the email client...

```
<a href="mailto:someaddress@email.com?subject=Subject Line Here">click to email</a>
```

Nearly any email client will take the subject parameter and set it as the subject line.

Comment: Actually,I want the outlook specifically.

Comment: So,is it possible what I need !!

Comment: I work under the expectation that I can't control (not should I control) the users choice of email client just as I can't control their choice of browser or OS.  Mobile users, Linux and Mac users, users without Outlook, users with Outlook and another email client set as their default... None of these users are going to have a good experience if you attempt to force them to use Outlook.  IMHO your best bet is handle all users gracefully and simply and let their system worry about their email client.

Comment: I am totally with you but that's what the client needs :)

Comment: That leads to the next question, though they may not care about the answer - Why do they require Outlook?  At this point it's rhetorical.

Comment: Because they are that side who have the money and they are in love with MS products :)